# How to mount configuration files into a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I have a postgres instance that I generally spin up using a `docker-compose.yml` file. It mounts some configuration files like this:

```
    volumes:
      - postgres-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./pg_hba.conf:/etc/pg_hba.conf
```

These files are located in the same folder as the `docker-compose.yml` file is.

My question is: how do I make a Pod that contains this container also mount these configuration files? I read something about PVC in Kubernetes but I'm having a hard time connecting the dots and going from the docker-compose way of thinking to the Kubernetes way of thinking.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest approach would be to store the files in a `ConfigMap` and mount those as volumes in the container.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  my.properties: |
    url=example.com
    username=username
    password=password
  index.html: |
    Hello world
```

```yaml
[...]
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      image: some-registry/some-image
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config/my.properties
        subPath: my.properties
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /some/different/path/index.html
        subPath: index.html
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: my-config
[...]
```

By that the `my.properties` file is mounted into `/etc/config` and `index.html` into `/some/different/path` of the `my-container` file system.

You can also generate the configmap from the file by `kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file /path/to/my.properties --from-file /path/to/index.html`

See [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) for more info on that.

Comment: In addition, you can create the ConfigMap from an existing file with `kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file /path/to/config.yaml`.

Comment: Oooh, I see! That actually helps me a lot, it seems like exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the help! (kubectl create is an amazing API that I didn't know about).

Comment: Thanks @Mago, added your hint to the answer.